# from data.dataloader import DataLoader as DL ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data'

Tags: python

[image]

I want to run a federated learning related code, but this error occurs

```
from data.dataloader import DataLoader as DL
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data'
```

There is a data file in the code folder, why does this error occur when running the train file.

Comment: What file contains the import? Please make a [mre]. We might also need to know your working directory and the value of your `sys.path`.

Comment: To be clear, I don't know what you're referring to by "train file" since `train` is a folder in this screenshot

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] for tips, like how to write a good title. You can [edit] the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.